# Using temp tables to improve inner join performance

Tags: sql, oracle, performance, join, temp-tables

I am working fairly large oracle database with few millon records in the transaction tables. I am required to do multiple inner joins to generate a report.

So here is the scenario:

a. I have to join 5 tables(say t1, t2...t5) for a report.

b. Each table has a identifier(say uid) that links these tables.

c. Since I am not interested in all records from these tables, I am creating temp tables(temp1, temp2...temp5) with only the required records. Each temp table will contain only one column - uid.

c. The result that I am looking for is an inner join of all these tables temp1-temp5. In other words, I am interested in uids that exist in all 5 temp tables.

d. Creation of temp5 requires some calculation. I have a function that accepts a the uid, queries another table, retrieves a number and does a calculation and returns a boolean value to the calling function indicating whether to include or exclude the uid in the list.

e. This logic of the function is very simple(though it requires to run a query everytime) and the function runs in few milliseconds.

Question: In order to improve the performance, during the creation of temp5, I pass the uids in temp1 instead of t5(based on my requirement described in (c)).

Original query:

```
SELECT uid FROM  t5 where calculate_function(uid) = 0.
```

Updated query:

```
SELECT uid FROM  temp1 where calculate_function(uid) = 0.
```

I was hoping that this query will improve the performance. But the query still takes 2-3 hours to execute even though temp1 contains just 20000 rows ( compared to t5 that contains few millon rows) and the function takes just few milliseconds.

Is there something I can do to improve the performance? Is there something wrong about my understanding of temp tables or how functions are supposed to be used in a query?

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: In Oracle it is very rarely a good idea to create temporary tables - not even global temporary tables, which is what you shoudl use if you do.  Just join the tables you need.

Comment: If you can, get rid of the function call and perform the equivalent logic in the SQL. Calling PL/SQL functions from SQL, millions of times over, takes a **long** time.

Comment: You can also consider using a function based index, more details on this can be found in the documentation - https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e41502/adfns_indexes.htm#ADFNS00505

Comment: According to https://asktom.oracle.com/pls/asktom/f%3Fp%3D100:11:0::::P11_QUESTION_ID:2153739600346754734 this may help if function call can't be removed: `SELECT uid FROM t5 where (select calculate_function(uid) from dual) = 0`

Comment: Thanks Tony and Yaron!

Comment: I am using global temporary table. I had all my joins in a single SQL query initially. But when I modified the query to use  temp tables, I noticed a significant improvement in performance. But I agree, calling PL/SQL functions so many times isn't good idea. I'll try moving that code into my query.

Comment: Using dual made the query 50% faster.